# GraalVM security of ahead of time compilation (AOT)

Tags: java, security, native, aot, graalvm

I apreciate head of time compilation of bytecode into native code, but doesn't it reintroduce security issues? E.g. isn't it missing runtime checks like checks for array bounds?

Okay if you compile trusted Java code it probably will not do anything wrong but there may be other scenarios.

Comment: If you would remove safety and security checks when compiling into native code, yes but why should you do so? Furthermore the runtime behavior would change, as some code may rely on exception thrown in such a situation. Therefore the native code have to behave exactly the same as regular byte code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that an ahead-of-time compiler wouldn't include the normal runtime checks into the compiled code. Moreover, if it didn't do this then it wouldn't create an ahead-of-time program that matched a regular program. That would be a bug.

The regular Hotspot just-in-time compiler in the established JDK turns bytecode into native code. What ahead-of-time compilation is doing is to do the work, well, ahead-of-time. There is an excellent video about how a just-in-time work by showing you the code of the [Graal JIT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFf15TvSXZ0&feature=youtu.be) which you can configure JDK11 to use.

By running the compiler ahead-of-time you get much faster startup time and a smaller memory footprint. You might not get such fast code at this point in time as a JIT compiler as the JIT compiler can do optimisations based on the data that the code encounters. An ahead-of-time compiler cannot guess which code paths will never be encountered.